# How to pass composite key from controller to jsp in spring and hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have Object class User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UserMst")
public class User implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long userId;

@Column(name="emailId")
private String emailId;

@Column(name="userName")
private String userName;

@Column(name="address")
private String address;

@Column(name="mobNo")
private BigDecimal mobNo;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "deptId")
private Department department;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "desgId")
private Designation designation;

@Column(name="grpId")
private int grpId ;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
  @JoinColumn(name = "sk"),
  @JoinColumn(name = "pk")})
private Config config ;

@Column(name="upw1")
private String upw1 ;

@Column(name="upw2")
private String upw2 ;

@Column(name="upw3")
private String upw3 ;

@Column(name="createdBy")
private String createdBy ;

@Column(name="creationDate")
private Timestamp creationDate;

@Column(name="loginStatus")
private String loginStatus;

@Column(name="hintId")
private int hintId ;

@Column(name="hintAns")
private String hintAns ;

@Column(name="otp")
private String otp ;
```

and another Object Config.java has composite key(sk, pk) which is foreign key of User object.

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "config")
 public class Config implements Serializable{

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)   
  private String pk;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private String sk;

  @Column(name="ds")
  private String ds;

  @Column(name="value")
  private String value;
```

Now I have list of Config and passed that list on jsp in which dropdown is there
and want option value bind to that composite key(sk,pk)

```html
<select name="userLevel" id="lvl_Id" class="form-control" size="0">
  <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
      <c:forEach var="levelList" items="${levelList}">
      <option value="<c:out value="${levelList.sk}|${levelList.pk}" />">${levelList.ds}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Anybody can help me out this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to pass the composite key to the controller side then you can pass the data in hidden field using html tag.

May be your problem will solve.

Answer (score 0):

${levelList.ds} whatever the data is stored in this list display in the select box. here simple "${levelList.ds}" data is displayed here because there is no ant data.

```html
<select name="userLevel" id="lvl_Id" class="form-control" size="0">
  <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
      <c:forEach var="levelList" items="${levelList}">
      <option value="${levelList.sk}|${levelList.pk}">${levelList.ds}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: Yeah, I got the composite key on jsp but now how to pass this composite key to the controller so that i can insert dropdown value to the table?